# Do TCP clients' ports and TCP servers' ports share the same address space?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, conflict, port-number

On the same machine, if a tcp client has occupied port 12345, for example, the client has connected to google.com, and then a tcp server tries to bind its listening port on 12345, is this allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "it depends" (on OS and socket options).

On Linux with `SO_REUSEADDR` on both sockets, the exact situation described is possible:

```
$ sudo netstat -panl |grep 12300
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12300         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3591/nc         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12300         127.0.0.1:25            ESTABLISHED 3547/nc         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            127.0.0.1:12300         ESTABLISHED 3548/exim4
```

...but only when the client gets there first. When the server is already listening, the same port can't be bound by client (and won't ever be automatically assigned to client, IIRC).

On Windows, with or without `SO_REUSEADDR`, *port is port* and `bind` fails (be it the server or the client who did it first).

Answer (score -2):

No. Port is port.

THAT SAID: Clashes rarely are there because normally servers start before the client ask for a non specified port (i.e. the client never sets a port number, his machine takes a free one).

And there are predefined ports for most servers.

http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt?number=1700

And ranges:

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPApplicationAssignmentsandServerPortNumberRang-2.htm

As you can see, registerd ports go to 49151 and from there they are reserved for dynamic use. So, client ports normally come from that range 49152 upward which services should not use.

Comment: Your answer is to "how to avoid conflicts", not to "whether such a conflict is allowed".

Comment: @xmllmx Learn reading. The conflict is avoided simple: do not use a Port number out of the range used for dynamic client ports. if you do not do that, there is no chance of conflict to start with.